# Is there way to display record month by month?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So.. I am trying to make record display by month by month.

For example,

```
    select X, Y, Z, (X + Y + Z) as total
from (
  select
    (select count(x) from table1 a, table2 b where date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-05-01') as X,
    (select count(y) from table3 a, table4 b where date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-05-01') as Y,
    (select count(z) from table5 a, table6 b where date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-05-01') as Z
  from dual
);
```

This will display count of x between those date range but if I display it like 2 columns, like first column display month, second column display X and display it month by month. So result would be like below. Is this doable in sql?

```
Month    ||     X      ||     Y     ||     Z     ||   Total
January  ||    125     ||    133    ||    155    ||    413
February ||    150     ||    123    ||    129    ||    402
March    ||    170     ||    177    ||    155    ||    502
....
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to group by month

```
Select count(X), TO_CHAR(PDATE , 'MONTH') AS Month_name

From TableA

Where PDATE between '2020-01-01' to '2020-01-31'
group by TO_CHAR(PDATE , 'MONTH')
```

Comment: this works but what happens if i want to query something that is made with many of this query? I mean, if this entire query is just for count for x? so select month_name, column1, column2 from ((select count(x) from tablea) as column1, (select count(y) from tableb) as column2)) from dual something like that?

Comment: Either Update your current question with some examples or put up a new question with more details.

Comment: Yes, it's doable, just give the sample data and expected result so people here can test it. My idea is first to group it and then apply analytical query to get month wise total

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to sort chronologically by the month, and assuming that pdate is an actual date data type, you'll need to include it in a numerical format in your order by. So something like this:

```
   select to_char(pdate,'Month') month, 
          count(*)
     from TableA
    where pdate between to_date('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
                    and to_date('2020-08-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
 group by to_char(pdate,'Month')
 order by to_char(pdate,'MM');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
To_char(trunc(pdate, 'mm' ), 'month' ), count(X)
From TableA
Group by trunc(pdate, 'mm' ) 
Order by trunc(pdate, 'mm' )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Transform Your Date to the Display Format Required, 'Month', but Sort by Date**

I assume you do not care what year your record is associated, so I convert the date to a string associated with the record's month.

Next, I aggregate by the record's month and perform a sort by a transformation of the record's month back in to a date as seen below:

```
--sample data---------------       
WITH smple ( record_month ) AS (
    SELECT
        to_char(last_ddl_time, 'Month') record_month
    FROM
        all_objects
)
--end sample data-----------  
SELECT
    record_month,
    COUNT(1)
FROM
    smple
GROUP BY
    record_month
ORDER BY
    to_date(record_month || '-01-2020', 'MONTH-DD-YYYY') ASC;
```